# creating breadcrumb on article page with php using two queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to have breadcrumb on my website looks like this: `Home / Category / Sub Category / Article` example: https://jsfiddle.net/10kLs0rc/

**table structures**

categories: `id -- parentid -- title`

articles: `id -- categoryid -- title -- content`

*

It's easy to print article's title to breadcrumb. But I also want to print category of article. (even subcategory if article has it. as you can see the example above.)

I think i need php code with double query, one for "categories" and other for "articles" table.

*

**EDIT**

Page i want to build called "article.php" user will visit: "article.php?id=1"

I can fetch all data I want, except articles parent categories.

Here is the code I simply have, and I want to create another query for fetching parent categories of article but I'm stuck.

```
<?php
$id =   $_GET['id'];
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE id='$id'");
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "
  <h3>$r[title]</h3>

        <p>$r[content]</p>
    ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: what have you worked on so far to get this going? Paste the PHP code here.

Comment: please also provide some more details, i.e. some data from db and what data you want to display in what format

Comment: @davejal NEVER pass user input directly into your queries without sanitising it first, that's a recipe for SQL injection. Look into using prepared statements.

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode ??? I didn't ask the question !!!

Comment: @davejal oops haha my bad, that was aimed at Lukasz :)

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode no prob, I know you're trying to help to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you want :

```
select
    `a`.`title` as `art_title`, 
    `a`.`content` as `art_content`,
    `c1`.`title` as `cat_title`, 
    `c2`.`title` as `cat_title_parent`
from `article` as `a`
left join `categories` as `c1`
    on `c1`.`id` = `a`.`categoryid`
left join `categories` as `c2`
    on `c2`.`id` = `c1`.`parentid`
where `a`.`id`=2;
```

And Here is the POC on [SQLFiddle [image: sqlfiddle]

So in your php :

```
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<i>';
    if(isset($r['cat_title_parent']))
        echo '/'.$r['cat_title_parent'];

    if(isset($r['cat_title']))
        echo '/'.$r['cat_title'];

    echo '</i><br />';
    echo '<h3>'.$r['art_title'].'</h3>';
    echo '<p>'.$r['art_content'].'</p>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But how to echo parent categories names? I'm suffering this now.

Comment: @Lukasz have you take a look at the SQLFiddle ?

Comment: I see but, i need to print them on php. (I'm beginner maybe I don't understand or i miss something. thats pretty possible.) I need to echo parent categories. example: `<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $handler->query
("SELECT * 
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN categories c1
    ON c1.id = a.categoryid
LEFT JOIN categories c2
    ON c2.id = c1.parentid
WHERE a.id='$id'");

while($r = $query->fetch()) {
  echo "
  <h3>$r[title]</h3>

        <p>$r[content]</p>
  ";
  }

?>`

Comment: if you look at the sqlfiddle (or [this one](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e3ef/2) ) you get back `cate` and `cate_parent` ; cate is the direct one for your article, and cate_parent is (if existe) the parent of the article category

Comment: thanks for all of efforts and helping me out. You need more than points.

Comment: @Lukasz not a problem ;) btw, add the tag SQL to your question, if someone need to search it'll be better as it's sql related